# Solving an equation involving factorial notation

Tags: permutations, factorial, quadratics

I was given this problem in the text book:

$$\frac{(n+4)!}{(n+2)!} = 6$$

$$n \in I $$

Since the textbook doesn't have the solution, I'm wondering if I'm right:

$$\frac{(n+4)!}{(n+2)!} \Rightarrow \frac{(n+4)(n+3)(n+2)!}{(n+2)!} \Rightarrow (n+4)(n+3)$$

$$\Rightarrow (n+4)(n+3)$$
$$\Rightarrow n^2+4n+3n+12$$
$$\Rightarrow n^2+7n+12$$

$$\Rightarrow n^2 + 7n + 12 = 6$$
$$\Rightarrow n^2+7n+6=0$$

$$\Rightarrow n^2+7n+6=0$$
$$\Rightarrow n^2 +6n + n + 6 = 0 $$

$$\Rightarrow n(n + 6)1(n+6) = 0$$

$$\Rightarrow (n+1)(n+6) = 0 $$

Then $n$ can be two possible values:

$$n+1=0 $$
$$n+6 = 0$$

$$n=-1 \ or \ n=-6$$

If I go back to the original equation and replace $n$ with $-1$:

$$\frac{(-1+4)!}{(-1+2)!} = \frac{(3)!}{(1)!} = \frac{3*2*1}{1} = \frac{6}{1}$$

If replace $n$ with $-6$:

$$\frac{(-6+4)!}{(-6+2)!} = \frac{(-2)!}{(-4)!} = \varnothing$$

So is $n = -1$ or am I wrong? There's no solution shown in the text book.

Comment: First of all the factorial $n!$ is only defined for $n\geq 0$  and $n$ integer (yes there are generalizations, but that should be specified if you are to consider it imo). Using $(n+4)(n+3) = 3\cdot 2 = 6 \cdot 1$ leaves only two choices for the two factors $(3,2)$ and $(6,1)$. Now use $(n+4) - (n+3) = 1$ to narrow it down further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already checked that when $n=-1$, then you get the equality you want, so that is definitely a solution. You can ignore the case $n=-6$ because the factorial is not defined for $n<0$. Your solution is correct.

The reason why the other "solution" $n=-6$ showed up is because it is a solution to the equation $(n+4)(n+3)=6$, which allows $n$ to be any real number. However, in the original equation, simply writing down $(n+2)!$ already implicitly implies that $n \ge -2$, restricting the space of your possible solutions.

As noted in the comment by Winther, it is assumed that $n$ is an integer, so solving $(n+4)(n+3)=6$ simply requires finding two integers whose product is $6$ and whose difference is $1$. This is a little bit quicker.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation! The way they're showing it in the book is by factoring a quadratic but that other way is something I will consider.